# excel within range of cells, is there a date entered

Tags: arrays, excel, date

Having some columns with either empty or a date in it, I need to get a true or false for a date present.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F       
1   Name    oDate   eDate   xDate   EndDate Status      
2   Lars        01-11-2015          ?   <=  TRUE
3   Erik                    ?   <=  FALSE
4   Niels           09-01-2015  10-02-2015  ?   <=  TRUE
5   Jens    02-02-2016      10-02-2015      ?   <=  TRUE
```

Tried with

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($AP2:$AP2;ISNUMBER($AP2);$AQ2:$AQ2;ISNUMBER($AQ2);$AR2:$AR2;ISNUMBER($AR2);$AS2:$AS2;ISNUMBER($AS2);$AT2:$AT2;ISNUMBER($AT2);$AU2:$AU2;ISNUMBER($AU2)) >= 1;"TRUE";"FALSE")
```

but that just checks if fields not empty.

Anyone?

Comment: There is an IsDate method, if I'm not mistaking

Comment: Version 2010 -> =isDate = #NAME? ;-) Or am I doing it wrong? (Obvious answer is Yes :))

Comment: Easy approach: =IF(COUNTBLANK(AP2:AU2)<=COLUMNS(AP2:AU2)-1;"TRUE";"FALSE")

Comment: Seems like isDate is only available for VBA. Try =IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(B3,"dd/mm/yyyy")))),"valid date","invalid date") instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Excel dates are just numbers formatted to suit (subject to being in the range 0 - 2958465) so say 23 September 1904 is just the same as dozen gross (1,728) without added context such as formatting. Provided the formatting is as you show it can be detected to use to differentiate say 11/02/2015 from 42,046:

```
=OR(CELL("format",B2)="D1",CELL("format",C2)="D1",CELL("format",D2)="D1",CELL("format",B2)="D1")
```

However since detecting the format of cells rather than content, a blank cell formatted as a date will count even without, in that case `00/01/1990` being displayed. (So you might also want a further check, such as that the sum of B:E cells is also greater than `0`, or that each is a positive number and not text.)